# Lazy loading table in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to find some examples of table using lazy loading to load info, namely rows. I had a good look but I don't seem to be able to find any good example anywhere (I don't want to use any add on like Viritin), I just want to do it from scratch. The documentation on the vaadin website doesn't really help [Table](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-table.html) so I was just wondering if anybody is aware of any good tutorial that explains what needs to be done. Perhaps an example might be better then. So here is a simple table displaying integers up to 5000. I will try to implement lazy loading here which is a very simple application and then hopefully I will be able to integrate the functionality easy in my own application. Here is the code.
My UI class (MyUI.java):

```
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        numberTable theTable = new numberTable();


        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("test!");

            }
        });

        layout.addComponents(button, theTable);
        layout.setMargin(true);
        layout.setSpacing(true);

        setContent(layout);
    }
```

And the table class (numberTable.java):

```
package my.vaadin.project.tableTest;

import com.vaadin.ui.Table;

public class numberTable extends Table
{
    public numberTable(){
        /*addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
        addContainerProperty("Mag",  Float.class, null);
        addItem(new Object[]{"Canopus",        -0.72f}, 1);
        addItem(new Object[]{"Arcturus",       -0.04f}, 2);
        addItem(new Object[]{"Alpha Centauri", -0.01f}, 3);*/
        addContainerProperty("Number", Integer.class, null);
        for(int i=1; i<=5000; i++){
            Integer itemID = new Integer(i);
            addItem(new Object[]{i},itemID);
        }
        setCaption("Rendering table");
        addStyleName("testTable");
        setPageLength(size());
        System.out.println("table created");
    }

}
```

I've read that to implement the lazy loading functionality I have to have a container that supports it, other than the table, that's my understanding.

Comment: What kind of data source do you have? Some of the containers in Vaadin support lazy loading.

Comment: Hi have a table (created in a class that extends Table)

Comment: A Table is the way to display data from a Container. How do you populate the Table? https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-table.html . The table retrieves the rows from the container as needed

Comment: I use a simple for loop to populate the table, if that's what you mean

Comment: @AndréSchild I have updated the thread, I thought that a practical example would be better, so here it is. I think that what's not really clear to me is the procedure, like, what do I need to do to implement that functionality? And I couldn't find any tutorial or blog explaining it exactly

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-container.html#datamodel.container.indexedcontainer), the `IndexedContainer` matches your needs. Or, if you want to implement a container yourself that supports lazy loading with `Table` then implement the `Container.Indexed` [interface](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Container.Indexed.html). You could browse the `IndexedContainer` source code for an example.

I have made a basic example for implementing the `Container.Indexed` interface:

```
public class MyContainer implements Container.Indexed {

    public Object nextItemId(Object itemId) { return ((Integer) itemId) + 1; }
    public Object prevItemId(Object itemId) { return ((Integer) itemId) - 1; }
    public Object firstItemId() { return 0; }
    public Object lastItemId() { return 5000; }
    public boolean isFirstId(Object itemId) { return Integer.valueOf(0).equals(itemId); }
    public boolean isLastId(Object itemId) { return Integer.valueOf(5000).equals(itemId); }

    public Item getItem(Object itemId) {
        PropertysetItem item = new PropertysetItem();
        item.addItemProperty("index", new ObjectProperty<Integer>((Integer) itemId));
        return item;
    }
    public Collection<?> getContainerPropertyIds() { return Arrays.asList("index"); }
    public Collection<?> getItemIds() { return Arrays.asList(IntStream.range(0, 5001).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new)); }
    public Property getContainerProperty(Object itemId, Object propertyId) { return new ObjectProperty<Integer>((Integer) itemId); }
    public Class<?> getType(Object propertyId) { return Integer.class; }
    public int size() { return 5001; }
    public boolean containsId(Object itemId) {
        Integer item = (Integer) itemId;
        return item >= 0 && item <= 5000;
    }
    public int indexOfId(Object itemId) { return (Integer) itemId; }
    public Object getIdByIndex(int index) { return index; }
    public List<?> getItemIds(int startIndex, int numberOfItems) { return Arrays.asList(IntStream.range(0, 5001).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new)).subList(startIndex, startIndex + numberOfItems); }

    public Item addItem(Object itemId) throws UnsupportedOperationException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    public Object addItem() throws UnsupportedOperationException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    public boolean removeItem(Object itemId) throws UnsupportedOperationException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    public boolean addContainerProperty(Object propertyId, Class<?> type, Object defaultValue) throws UnsupportedOperationException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    public boolean removeContainerProperty(Object propertyId) throws UnsupportedOperationException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    public boolean removeAllItems() throws UnsupportedOperationException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    public Object addItemAfter(Object previousItemId) throws UnsupportedOperationException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    public Item addItemAfter(Object previousItemId, Object newItemId) throws UnsupportedOperationException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    public Object addItemAt(int index) throws UnsupportedOperationException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    public Item addItemAt(int index, Object newItemId) throws UnsupportedOperationException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }

}
```

It is read-only. Items have only one property `"indexed"` that is the index of the item, between 0 and 5000 inclusive. As you can see, it is a lot of work, so you should make use of a built-in container if possible.

Comment: thanks for the code. I've noticed something rather interesting. In my own example code. I display all the elements in the table, so I changed this line `setPageLength(size());` to `setPageLength(100);` . Lo and behold, lazy loading works.Does it mean that Table have lazy loading inbuilt? The only thing though is that when I apply that to my own application (i don't have integers in the table rows but objects) lazy loading works OK when you scroll down, but when you scroll up again some of the table rows are empty

Comment: Sounds strange, maybe a bug, can't say without the code.

Comment: Well no, I mean if you think about it. With `setPageLength(size());` you are essentially saying to display all the rows, so you can't have lazy loading doing anything as everything is there, wherease with `setPageLength(100);` you only have 100 rows displayed and the other ones are loaded via lazy loading (providing it's enabled as it seems it is). The code is included by the way as I've updated the thread

Comment: My comment was on your last sentence (when you scoll up again).

Comment: ah OK. I think perhaps what might help is a way to 'repaint' - for the lack of a better word - the elements of the table, a sort of table refresh if you like (I had a look around and found something that might help, the method `refreshRowCache()`), the problem is though, when should that fire? Meaning, there doesn't seem to be a way to fire that when the scrollbar goes up and it's released...unless vaadin has some other method that could do that...